# Type-cast to type-alias in inline comment type (Flow)

Tags: flowtype

I have a vanilla JavaScript file using Flow, like so:

```js
// @flow
/*:: type orderType = number; */
let ot = 0 /*:: as orderType */;
```

but I get error

> Invalid type cast syntax. Use the form `(<expr>: <type>)` instead of the form `<expr> as <type>`.

However, trying that syntax also gives me an error:

```js
let ot = 0 /*:: : orderType */;    // ■■■■ Unexpected token `:`, expected the token `;`
```

Is type-casting with type-alias not working with comment types in Flow?

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax seem to be

```js
let op /*: orderType*/ = 0;
```

assuming you use `number` and not `Number`.